# filter data based on multiple values seperated by comma within a column

Tags: r, dplyr

Need to filter data from a table, where I have an input table as below

```
Emp_id = c(121,122,191,181,277,333)  
salary = c(7838,8389,8940,9491,10042,10593)  
Country = c("USA","USA","UK","USA","UK","USA")

df = data.frame(Emp_id,salary,Country)
```

and I have one more single character separated by a comma as below:

```
Emp_lst = "121,191,181"
```

Now, I need to filter df rows based on values in `Emp_lst`. For that, I have tried the code below, but I am getting 0 rows

```
library(dplyr)
df_flter = df %>% filter(Emp_id %in% Emp_lst)
```

Any Modification required in above code?

Answer (score 0):

We could use a regex based approach here by converting your CSV list of employee IDs into an alternation:

```r
regex <- paste0("^(?:", gsub(",", "|", Emp_lst, fixed=TRUE), ")$")
df[grepl(regex, df$Emp_id), ]

  Emp_id salary Country
1    121   7838     USA
3    191   8940      UK
4    181   9491     USA
```

**Data:**

```
Emp_id <- c(121,122,191,181,277,333)  
salary <- c(7838,8389,8940,9491,10042,10593)  
Country <- c("USA","USA","UK","USA","UK","USA")
df <- data.frame(Emp_id,salary,Country)
Emp_lst <- "121,191,181"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Emp_lst = "121,191,181"` to `Emp_lst = c(121,191,181)`

```
Emp_id = c(121,122,191,181,277,333)  
salary = c(7838,8389,8940,9491,10042,10593)  
Country = c("USA","USA","UK","USA","UK","USA")

Emp_lst = c(121,191,181)

library(dplyr)
df_flter = df %>% filter(Emp_id %in% Emp_lst)
df_flter

  Emp_id salary Country
1    121   7838     USA
2    191   8940      UK
3    181   9491     USA
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can not change to c(121,191,181) I have multiple values like that.

Comment: is there any statement is there to convert Emp_lst = c(121,191,181) from Emp_lst = "121,191,181"

Comment: You mean like this `as.numeric(strsplit(Emp_lst, ",")[[1]])` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

1. `unlist` `Emp_lst` with the use of `strsplit` to have access to all 3 numbers
2. usiong `filter_all` as a variation of `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
Emp_lst <- unlist(strsplit(Emp_lst,","))
filter_all(df, any_vars(. %in% Emp_lst))
```

Output:

```
  Emp_id salary Country
1    121   7838     USA
2    191   8940      UK
3    181   9491     USA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `Emp_lst` on comma and select rows where `Emp_id` matches.

```
Emp_lst = "121,191,181"
subset(df, Emp_id %in% strsplit(Emp_lst, ',\\s*')[[1]])

#  Emp_id salary Country
#1    121   7838     USA
#3    191   8940      UK
#4    181   9491     USA
```